# How to properly implement interface for dynamic hashmaps?

Tags: typescript

Given a data structure, I'm building a hashmap based on that. This is resulting in the following hashmap:

```
{ ZONE: { 
     Cameras: { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     Speakers: { source: {}, layer: {} } 
  }, 
  BUILDING:  
   { '04681e69-5f3e-4171-8722-0b5b3eafda99': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     '18ef1765-8aaf-4028-a7f4-be712f6b007f': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     '94b24ab4-80ee-4f62-a976-2efb53967d91': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     'bfc8fd5b-97cd-4f1e-b649-32c2dedcbb76': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     '9ce18bc9-3e00-474d-bacf-640073c5680e': { source: {}, layer: {} } }, 
  FLOOR: { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
  ROOM: { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
  DOOR: { source: {}, layer: {} } }
```

For some cases (e.g. ZONE), the hash has the following structure:

```
ZONE: {
   type: { source: {}, layer: {}
}
```

However, the structure change when it the data is inside the BUILDING hash, like the structure below:

```
BUILDING: {
  buildingId: {
    source: {},
    layer: {}
  }
}
```

This object is being created dynamically, so, I don't know whether we could have different types other than ZONE, BUILDING, etc.. but, I at least know that, the structures supported are those ones.

Thinking on it, I created the following interfaces:

```
/**
 * Determines the information to be supported by each layerhash
 */
export interface ILayerHash {
    /**
     * layer where the features will live on
     */
    layer: VectorLayer;
    /**
     * Source of information for all markers
     */
    source: VectorSource;
}

/**
 * Determines the structure of the hashmap which serves as reference for each layer and its vector
 * For example:
 * {
 *    BUILDING: {
 *      layer: Object,
 *      source: Object
 *    }
 * }
 */
export interface ILayersHashmap {
    [key: string]: ILayerHash;
}
```

In theory `ZONE` and `BUILDING` seems to have the same shape.

However, while trying to create the hashmap.. I start to struggle with the signatures.

I want to avoid to use `any` as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

During my testing, I assigned `VectorSource` to `{}`, just so that I could test it with the value that you have provided. I think you were pretty close to the result, so I've tried to use your variables name as much as possible

```
export interface ILayerHash {
    layer: {};
    source: {};
}


type buildingObjects = "ZONE" | "BUILDING"| "FLOOR" | "ROOM" | "DOOR"

type iFullBuildingModel = {
  [buildingStuff in buildingObjects]: ILayerHash | {
    [internalIds: string]: ILayerHash
  }
}

const u: iFullBuildingModel = { ZONE: { 
     Cameras: { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     Speakers: { source: {}, layer: {} } 
  }, 
  BUILDING:  
   { '04681e69-5f3e-4171-8722-0b5b3eafda99': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     '18ef1765-8aaf-4028-a7f4-be712f6b007f': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     '94b24ab4-80ee-4f62-a976-2efb53967d91': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     'bfc8fd5b-97cd-4f1e-b649-32c2dedcbb76': { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
     '9ce18bc9-3e00-474d-bacf-640073c5680e': { source: {}, layer: {} } }, 
  FLOOR: { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
  ROOM: { source: {}, layer: {} }, 
  DOOR: { source: {}, layer: {} } }
```

Please change it back to `VectorSource` and let me know if you face any issues.

As a successful test result my variable `u` doesn't show compile errors

Incase you want one of the keys from `buildingObjects` to not be available, you can just add a `?` in `iFullBuildingModel` like so :

```
type iFullBuildingModel = {
  [buildingStuff in buildingObjects]?: ILayerHash | {
    [internalIds: string]: ILayerHash
  }
}
```